# Intent does not work in same way all the time in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

There are 2-3 ways to use `Intent` to start New Activity.
Mostly, I am using

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent("com.Example.Jeeten.Connection");
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

But sometimes, It does not work, **It shows error `Activity` not found** and in that case If I use

```
Intent openStartingPoint = new Intent(Connection.this, Hello.class);
startActivity(openStartingPoint);
```

then It works fine. What can be the issue with this ?

Comment: can you please explain with one example when first way not work

Comment: You should read up on the different constructors of the `Intent` class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent()

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, it shows error activity not found.

Comment: @JeetenParmar : first approach not work only when you forget to define same action(in your case `com.Example.Jeeten.Connection`) for Activity using `intent-filter` in AndroidManifest

Comment: Intent provide no of constructor for various way to start activity so please understood Intent various constructor...

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK, Connection is actually Launcher Activity. so your mean, I will need to use intent-filter action ?

Comment: @JeetenParmar : add `<action android:name="com.Example.Jeeten.Connection" />` with Launcher Activity intent-filter

Answer (score 0):

When u make an activity, u have to register it in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<activity
        android:name=".Connection"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.Example.Jeeten.CONNECTION" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In the above code `<activity android:name` represents your activity class(Case sensitive),in your case its `Connection` and `Hello`.Next is `<action android:name` in this you specify by what name are you going to refer to the activity(its a good practice to put the last word all in uppercase `CONNECTION`).
So make sure you have two such activities in your xml file.In case one of the activity is your starting point of your app,modify the `<intent-filter>` like this

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```